# Printing in WPF using PrintDialog and FixedDocument

Tags: .net, wpf, printing

My current application I am building is using WPF printing components (FixedDocument as the main content provider, and PrintDialog for the actual printing)

The problem I am having is that when I direct the user to select a printer using the PrintDialog, a messagebox comes up (along with a canceled ShowDialog result) asking the user to download the 'Microsoft XML Paper Specification Essentials Pack'.  (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b8dcffdd-e3a5-44cc-8021-7649fd37ffee&DisplayLang=en)

The hardship comes in because, while my users are running .net 3.5sp1 and .net 4.0, their computers have accounts and group policies that restrict them from downloading and installing components.  Getting a new patch through the central IT department takes a great amount of time.

Did Microsoft really implement printing that requires this package without including it in the .net runtime framework?  Is there a another way for the user to select a printer and print a FixedDocument?

Thanks for any help!
-Corey